# Angular- Constitutive loop ngFor in ngFor with indexes i and j

Tags: html, angular

I want to use constitutive loop ngFor in ngFor with indexes i and j:

```
<div *ngFor="let tables of seatingArrangement; let i = index" [value]="tables.Id">
    <div class="ciclegraph circleposition{{i}}" *ngFor="let guest of tables.GuestsList; let j=index">
        <div class="circle" id="circle{{j}}">{{guest.guest_first_name+ " "+ guest.guest_last_name}} </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but the indexes don't work as expected.
when I use it, parent index i does not progress, while index j does.

```
<div _ngcontent-ptr-c103="" class="ciclegraph circleposition0"><div _ngcontent-ptr-c103="" class="circle" id="circle0" style="transform: rotate(630deg) translate(100px) rotate(-630deg);">Sara Eliyahu </div></div>
<div _ngcontent-ptr-c103="" class="ciclegraph circleposition0"><div _ngcontent-ptr-c103="" class="circle" id="circle1">Chagit Eliyahu </div></div>
<div _ngcontent-ptr-c103="" class="ciclegraph circleposition0"><div _ngcontent-ptr-c103="" class="circle" id="circle2">Tamar Eliyahu </div></div>
```

Comment: How many `tables` are there in `seatingArrangment`? Try printing out `{{ seatingArrangement.length }}` to make sure there isn't just one element.

Comment: seems to be working here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dugxpk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html What exactly do you want to do?